# Auto-mapper mapping overwriting nested child entity properties

Tags: c#, .net, object, nested, automapper

I just started using Automapper and blocked with one particular behavior regards to nested child entities.

While updating the child objects of a parent object, Automapper is replacing the child object in destination object with a new instance created using data from Target data instead of copying property by property.  To better explain the problem, I have copied the test code below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Mapper.CreateMap<PersonDTO, Person>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<UserLoginDTO, UserLogin>();

        Person pmodel = new Person()
        {
            Id = 10,
            FullName = "XYZ",
            LoginInfo = new UserLogin() { Id = 10, UserName = "xyz" }
        };

        PersonDTO pdto = new PersonDTO()
        {
            Id = 10,
            FullName = "XYZ",
            LoginInfo = new UserLoginDTO() { Id = 10, UserName = "abc" }
        };

        pmodel.Initiated();
        pmodel.LoginInfo.Initiated();
        Console.WriteLine("model => LoginInfo => IsInitiated : {0}", pmodel.LoginInfo.IsInitiated);
        Mapper.Map<PersonDTO, Person>(pdto, pmodel);
        Console.WriteLine("model => LoginInfo => IsInitiated : {0}", pmodel.LoginInfo.IsInitiated);

    }
}

public class PersonDTO
{
    public int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public String FullName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    public UserLoginDTO LoginInfo { get; set; }
}

public class UserLoginDTO
{

    public int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public String UserName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class Person : BaseEntity
{
    private int _id;
    private string _name;
    private UserLogin _loginInfo;

    public int Id { 
        get { return _id;  }
        set { _id= value; }
    }

    public String FullName
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public UserLogin LoginInfo { get { return _loginInfo; } set { _loginInfo = value; } }

}

public class UserLogin : BaseEntity
{
    private int _id;
    private string _userName;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }

    public String UserName
    {
        get { return _userName; }
        set { _userName= value; }
    }
}


public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    private bool _isInitiated = false;

    public bool IsInitiated { get { return _isInitiated; } }

    public void Initiated()
    {
        this._isInitiated = true;

    }
}
```

Output of the above code is:

Before mapping : model => LoginInfo => IsInitiated : True
After mapping : model => LoginInfo => IsInitiated : False

My requirement is to retain the IsInitiated property after mapping.  Am I missing something here.

Comment: Check out any of the related questions in order to find a work-around.

Comment: I checked related posts and none of them are close to my problem.  My friend suggested a solution to ignore the nested objects and in AfterMap event process the nested objects.  I posted this question to find better solution from experts.

Comment: Ah, I misinterpreted some of the linked questions. Looking at the wiki for Automapper, it appears that the Ignore() method might accomplish what you're looking for. Something like Mapper.CreateMap<UserLoginDTO, UserLogin>().ForMember("IsInitiated", src => src.Ignore());

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately this is not working.  From the behavior what I understand is, while updating the LoginInfo property in Person, AutoMapper, replacing this with a new instance of UserLogin object.

Comment: When I copy and run your exact code, I get model => LoginInfo => IsInitiated : True
model => LoginInfo => IsInitiated : True

Comment: However, from my testing, it appears that you can choose to ignore the mapping of the entire child object, or individual properties on that object.

Comment: I got it. I was using a old version of Automapper (1.x).  I verified the behavior using latest version and as mentioned by you, it is working as expected.  My bad, I missed this basic check.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. i ended up using the return value of that mapping method.

```js
var result = Mapper.Map<PersonDTO, Person>(pdto, pmodel);
```

and added an explicit ignore for the properties i didnt want overwritten.

```js
  Mapper.CreateMap<PersonDTO, Person>()
.ForMember(d => d.IsInitiated, op => op.Ignore());
```

Comment: This method is useful, when the source and destination objects have same property, but we want Automapper not to copy that specific property from source to destination.  In my case, the nested child object in destination was replaced by object from source instead of mapping that child object using a definition.  However that behavior seems to be defect in older version but fixed in latest version.